# Slicer by Measure Text Result

Tags: powerbi, dax, slicers

I’m just starting out in my power BI journey and felt that I may find the answers I’m looking for on here

I have a table- let’s call it customers. And a visual showing some customer metrics in the form of a table. For each customer I have a few measures returning text options. Let’s say there’s a measure called high value that returns the text “top purchaser, average purchaser, lower purchaser” And another measure called customer age that returns the text values “New customer”,”Average customer”, and “Long term customer”

If I wanted to apply a slicer where I can filter by the result of high value or customer age (or maybe both)- like for example, I wanted to see only customers that are "top purchaser" and "new customers" what’s the best way to go about it?! I’ve watched about a hundred YouTube videos and scoured some threads but can’t find a good solution! I would love to have a filter that’s dynamic for the options returned by the measure but am fine with hard coding in the options as well as they do not change often.

I've tried making a slicer with parameters but it does not seem to work properly :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating a filter (slicer) for 'Customer Age' or 'Customer Value', you could try to create 'Calculated Columns' instead of using 'Measures'.

There is a difference between Measures and Calculated Columns(or columns).
Please refer this link for the detail. https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/What-is-the-difference-between-a-measure-and-calculated-column/td-p/2900507

For this case, what you could do is for each customers(rows) of 'customer' table, create 'Customer Age' and 'Customer Value' calculated columns by

1. Right click the customer table at 'Data' panel on the right, and select New column.
2. Input the dax code similar like below (The conditions are made up):

```
Customer Value = 
       IF(AND(Customer[Purchase]>=0, Customer[Purchase]<100), "Lower Purchaser", 
       IF(AND(Customer[Purchase]>=100, Customer[Purchase]<1000), "Average Purchaser", 
       IF(Customer[Purchase]>=1000, "Top Purchaser", 
       "Other")))
```

3. After creating the column, drag the column to the slicer. You could change the slicer style in 'Visualiztion' panel -> 'Slicer settings'.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: It is incredibly helpful! That absolutely fixes my problem, thank you so much!

Comment: I am glad that the problem is fixed. Thank you for your feedback!